# Jest fails to load Primeng css files

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, primeng

I'm using Jest version 26.6.3 to test Angular components. The unit tests for any components that use [Primeng's checkbox component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/checkbox) fail during the compileComponents step with the error "Failed to load checkbox.css":

```
Failed: "Failed to load checkbox.css"

       7 |
       8 | describe('CheckboxComponent', () => {
    >  9 |   beforeEach(async () => {
         |   ^
      10 |     await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      11 |       imports: [CheckboxModule],
      12 |       declarations: [CheckboxComponent, FieldLabelComponent],

      at Env.beforeEach (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:46:24)
      at context.<computed> (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:4309:39)
      at Suite.<anonymous> (src/app/@shared/forms/checkbox/checkbox.component.spec.ts:9:3)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:407:30)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:167:47)
      at Suite.<anonymous> (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:4227:33)
```

There are no files in my codebase named checkbox.css and no references to it anywhere either, so I'm assuming the css file is from Primeng. I've tried including `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` in the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` options, with no changes.

What might be causing this error? I'll include some relevant files below:

This is the full test function that fails

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { CheckboxModule } from 'primeng/checkbox';
import { createComponent, getControlDisplayValue } from 'src/tests/test-utils';
import { FieldLabelComponent } from '../form-field/field-label/field-label.component';
import { CheckboxComponent } from './checkbox.component';

describe('CheckboxComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [CheckboxModule],
      declarations: [CheckboxComponent, FieldLabelComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  });
```

This is the template for the component:

```html
<p-checkbox [inputId]="inputId" [formControl]="control" [binary]="true" [class.small-checkbox]="small"></p-checkbox>
<label [for]="inputId" [class.small-label]="small">
  <app-field-label [label]="label" [required]="required" [extraSmall]="small"></app-field-label>
</label>
```

Here's the jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "jest-preset-angular",
  roots: ["src"],
  coverageDirectory: "reports",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setup-jest.ts"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/$1",
    "@core": ["<rootDir>/src/app/@core"],
    "@core/(.*)": ["<rootDir>/src/app/@core/$1"],
    "@shared": ["<rootDir>/src/app/@shared"],
    "@shared/(.*)": ["<rootDir>/src/app/@shared/$1"],
    "@env": "<rootDir>/src/environments/environment",
  },
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
      tsconfig: "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
    },
  },
  // Do not ignore librairies such as ionic, ionic-native or bootstrap to transform them during unit testing.
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!(jest-test|@ng-bootstrap))"],
};
```

And here's the tsconfig.spec.json file

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "allowJs": true,
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
  },
  "files": ["src/setup-jest.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.mock.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a fix for this? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, same here :(

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this issue is caused by Primeng components failing to load css files specified in the `styleUrls` of the component decorator when tests run. I was able to resolve this by adding the following code inside the `beforeEach` function and before calling `TestBed.configureTestingModule`:

```
TestBed.overrideComponent(Checkbox, { set: { styleUrls: [] } });
```

Because multiple Primeng components were causing this error in some of my tests, I eventually pulled the `TestBed.overrideComponent` call into a helper function:

```
export function removeStyleUrlsFrom(tokens: Type<any>[]): void {
  tokens.forEach((token) => TestBed.overrideComponent(token, { set: { styleUrls: [] } }));
}
```

This can be used in this way:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  removeStyleUrlsFrom([Checkbox, Calendar, Dropdown]);
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      CheckboxModule,
      CalendarModule,
      DropdownModule,
    ],
    .....
  }).compileComponents();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your workaround. I think this should be posted as an issue (don't know if in primeng or jest) so it could be fixed correctly.

Comment: Thank you to your response :)

After some research, the problem is that prime components are not compiled in a format suitable for tests. Can you try this please  : in your package.json => "test": "ngcc && jest",

Comment: I have this same problem and the suggestion to use "test": "ngcc && jest" in package.json unfortunately did not help. Overriding the styleUrls seems to be doing the trick though.