# Failed to load multiselect.css in PrimeNG when trying import module eg MultiSelectModule

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

I have an error in a browser

```
GET http://localhost:3000/multiselect.css 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load multiselect.css
```

when I'm trying to import MultiSelectModule in component module file:

```
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/multiselect';
@NgModule({
...
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, MultiSelectModule],
...
```

I have imported other modules in app.modules.ts like: `BrowserModule`, `BrowserAnimationsModule`

In angular.json I have

```
"styles": [
     "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
     "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
     "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
```

but it doesn't work for me so I import these styles in main.ts

```
import 'primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css';
import 'primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "12.2.6",
    "primeflex": "3.1.0",
    "primeicons": "5.0.0",
    "primeng": "12.2.2",
...
```

Compiled without errors.

When import less advanced element like p-button I don't have errors.

Where can be a problem?

Comment: The error seems to be very similar to this [Jest fails to load Primeng css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69273235/jest-fails-to-load-primeng-css-files) but I have it in running application.

Comment: The component works when I remove:
`styleUrls: ['./multiselect.css']`
from:
`node_modules\primeng\fesm2015\primeng-multiselect.js`
 in line 1019.

Comment: This is the same problem but without solution: https://githubmemory.com/repo/primefaces/primeng/issues/10457

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution so I hope someone will find better solution:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const primeNgCss = [
    ['primeng/resources/components/multiselect/multiselect.css', './multiselect.css'],
    ['primeng/resources/components/button/button.css', './button/button.css']
];

const plugins = [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: primeNgCss.map( file => { return {
            from: require.resolve(file[0]),
            to: file[1]
        } } )
    }),
...
```